# Insert additional content into parsley error

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I would like my parsley JS validation errors to render like this:

```
<span id="parsley-id-8333" class="form-error filled">
    <span class="parsley-required">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
        Error Message Goes Here
    </span>
</span>
```

How can I modify this function to append the `<i>` inside my `errorTemplate`?

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
  errorsWrapper: '<span class="form-error"></span>',
  errorTemplate: '<span></span>'
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is: what happens for multiple error messages for the same field?

If having one triangle is fine for you, then it's easily achieved by adding your icon to the wrapper:

```
errorsWrapper: '<span class="form-error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>',
errorTemplate: '<span></span>'
```

You'll get something compatible with what you were looking for:

```
<span id="parsley-id-8333" class="form-error filled">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
    <span class="parsley-required">
        Error Message Goes Here
    </span>
</span>
```

Of course, you don't want it to appear unless there's actually an error, so you'll need some CSS rule(s) to hide it otherwise, like:

```
.form-error:not(.filled) i { display: none; }
```

If you **really** need it in the `errorTemplate`, then I'm afraid there's no easy way, but it wouldn't be too hard to add it yourself with javascript. You can listen to the `parsley:form:error` event, search for error spans and prepend your `<i>`...

Comment: Hi Marc.  Thanks for your answer.  I've successfully added your solution - but there's a problem.  If I reset the form using .parsley().reset() then the `<i>` is lost.  Any ideas on how I can ensure the `<i>` shows every time?

Comment: I just noticed it's Marc-André - sorry for calling you by the wrong name :P

Comment: Mmm, that's a good point, and I consider this a bug. I'll fix it, should be easy.